# How can I get the value of a selected answer and match it with the right answer from the backend in flutter Streambuilder?

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart, stream-builder

I am trying to building a marker for a cbt app in flutter. a bit new to this.
I've gotten the questions and the answers from the backend into a stream. I'm trying to identify each value to be able to increase a counter for result if each selected value and answer is the same...

Below is what I have done... And I've tried to find a suitable way, not working...
Still i haven't gotten, pls help. I'm using php mysql for backend. Help

```
var radioItem = [];
  int a = 1;

...
...

Column questionList(
      id, question, option1, option2, option3, option4, option5, answer) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(id.toString() + ' ' + question),
        RadioListTile(
          activeColor: HexColor('AB1426'),
          groupValue: radioItem,
          title: Text(
            option1,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
          ),
          value: option1.toString(),
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              radioItem[a] = val.toString();
              a++;
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile(
          activeColor: HexColor('AB1426'),
          groupValue: radioItem,
          title: Text(
            option2,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
          ),
          value: option2.toString(),
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              radioItem[a] = val.toString();
              a++;
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile(
          activeColor: HexColor('AB1426'),
          groupValue: radioItem,
          title: Text(
            option3,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
          ),
          value: option3.toString(),
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              radioItem[a] = val.toString();
              a++;
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile(
          activeColor: HexColor('AB1426'),
          groupValue: radioItem,
          title: Text(
            option4,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
          ),
          value: option4.toString(),
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              radioItem[a] = val.toString();
              a++;
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile(
          activeColor: HexColor('AB1426'),
          groupValue: radioItem,
          title: Text(
            option5,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
          ),
          value: option5.toString(),
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              radioItem[a] = val.toString();
              a++;
            });
          },
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        Text(
          radioItem[a],
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 23),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

and I'm using streamBuilder to access them list from the backend.
Below is the code...

```
                           StreamBuilder<List>(
                              stream: _streamController.stream,
                              builder: (BuildContext context,
                                  AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                  return ListView(
                                    children: [
                                      for (Map document in snapshot.data)
                                        questionList(
                                          document['id'],
                                          document['question'],
                                          document['option1'],
                                          document['option2'],
                                          document['option3'],
                                          document['option4'],
                                          document['option5'],
                                          document['answer'],
                                        ),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                  // ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
                                }
                                // else if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                //     SocketException.closed()) {
                                //   // ignore: avoid_print
                                //   print('dfgdfgdgf');
                                // }
                                return Center(
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                top: 20),
                                            child: Row(
                                              children: const [
                                                Text(
                                                  ' Loading Questions...',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                                    fontSize: 14,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          const SpinKitCircle(
                                              color: Colors.grey),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
```

Kindly help, i can't figure out the logic to proceed.
Thanks.

Comment: Anyone? I've tried...

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the parameter answer is the right answer. So you just need to compare what user choose and this answer field. (if answer is not it, you should store the correct answer in your backend in order to compare).

create a function to compare it:

```
bool _compare(String selected, String rightAnswer){
  if(selected == rightAnswer){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Call this function on onChangeVal:

```
onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              radioItem[a] = val.toString();
              bool rightAnwser = _compare(val.toString(), answer); //response here
              a++;
            });
          },
```

Comment: This only solves for one, like it's there already, I'm looking for a way to auto compare for all 50 questions

Comment: No man, just store every correct answer in the backend and reutilize this code.

Comment: if i click on the right one, and select another and i rethink or resolve and i pick the right one again in the same question, the counter increases twice.(Basically if i click twice)